# How do I notify user at a particular time in the application

Tags: windows-phone-7

Now I have an application running on Windows Phone 7. I have a requirement - I have to notify a user at a particular time. Say (for example). When the phone clock strikes 5:00 PM then I need to display a message that "Your coffee is ready!". How do i do this?. or in simple words I need to execute the business logic of my app according to phone's time.

Please Help!

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

There are currently no APIs available to do this.
It is hoped/expected that this will be addressed in the Mango update but the specific details of the update are not yet available.

The best alternative currently available is to send a [push notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) (probably a toast) at the required time.

Comment: Toast notification APIs are indeed in Mango and were shown off at MIX

Comment: @Richard Szalay - Taost notifications are available now. They are being extended in terms of functionality in Mango. I was refering to being able to run code at a specific time with regard to Mango. We know that "Live Agents" will be able to run on a schedule or in response to specific system events. We don't yet know if this will include the ability to run at a specific time or how integration with system alarms (which is also in Mango) will work.

Comment: I was referring to local toast APIs (rather than having to send an HTTP request from the phone to the phone). In Mango, calendar-style alarms can be set to run at a certain time, background agents can be run "periodically" (currently around 30 minutes), but background agents cannot be run at specific times.